# RAILS + PaperClip - store resized image only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

My model looks like:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :image, 
                    :styles => { :small => "50x50#" },
                    :default_style => :small                   

  validates_attachment :image,
                       content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg",   
                                      "image/gif", "image/png"] }
end
```

RAILS stores the image twice: as original size, and as resized defined in `:small`. I would like to store only resized image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can simply define a style for :original to have paperclip replace the original with that size.

```
:styles => { :original => '300x168>', :cropped_thumb => {:geometry => "50x50#", :jcrop => true}, ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, puneet18.

This model do the job:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :image, 
                    :styles => { :original => "50x50#" },
                    :default_style => :original

  validates_attachment :image,
                       content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif",
                                       "image/png"] }
end
```